# Dos batch file how to do string replacement

Tags: batch-file, dos

HI i am very new to DOS batch shell scripting, i would like to know how to do string replacement, i had str1 with / i need to replace / with _(underscore) but not at front

```
set str1=/a/b/c/d

set str2=%str1:/=_%
```

returns me _a_b_c_d but i need a_b_c_d

Thanks,
Sanat.

Answer (score 3):

to remove the first character from a string, use:

```
set str3=%str2:~1%
```

In fact, you don't have to use different variables. The following lines work fine:

```
set str=/a/b/c/d
set str=%str:/=_% 
set str=%str:~1%
```